# Getting and deleting an object which was created in a DLL

Tags: delphi, interop

I have a dll written in C++. It looks like this:

header file:

```
#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

#include "SpeedTreeRT_1_8.h"

DllExport CSpeedTreeRT* NewSpeedTree(void);
DllExport void DeleteTree(CSpeedTreeRT* handle);
DllExport bool LoadTree(CSpeedTreeRT* handle, const unsigned char* pBlock, unsigned int nNumBytes);
```

cpp file:

```
CSpeedTreeRT* NewSpeedTree(void) {
    return new CSpeedTreeRT();
}

void DeleteTree(CSpeedTreeRT* handle) {
    delete handle;
}

bool LoadTree(CSpeedTreeRT* handle, const unsigned char* pBlock, unsigned int nNumBytes) {
    return handle->LoadTree(pBlock, nNumBytes);
}
```

Delphi type definitions:

```
TNewSpeedTreeFunc = function (): Cardinal; cdecl;
TLoadTreeFunc = function (AHandle: Cardinal; const ABlock: String; ANumBytes: Cardinal): Boolean; cdecl;
TDeleteTreeFunc = procedure (AHandle: Integer); cdecl;
```

I then use LoadLibrary to load dll into delphi application.

```
DllHandle: Cardinal;
NewSPeedTreeFunc : TNewSpeedTreeFunc;
LoadTreeFunc: TLoadTreeFunc;
DeleteTreeFunc: TDeleteTreeFunc;

DllHandle := LoadLibrary('SpeedTreeFT.dll');

@NewSpeedTreeFunc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'NewSpeedTree');
@LoadTreeFunc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'LoadTree');
@DeleteTreeFunc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'DeleteTree');


SpeedTreeHandle := NewSpeedTreeFunc;

    ... call other functions here ...

DeleteTreeFunc(SpeedTreeHandle);

FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
```

Dll exports other functions besides LoadTree, I just removed them for clarity.

What happens is if I run it once, everything is ok, I can call other functions in dll and I get the expected results. When I run it the second time, I get Access Violation exception on calling NewSpeedTree. I also noticed that a call to DeleteTree doesn't release memory from application.

Am I doing it the right way in dll? What could be causing this problem?

EDIT1: Provided more information in code blocks.

Comment: Not enough information here. Show a [mcve].

Comment: Indeed, there's not enough here for us to even guess what might be wrong. For example, what are the function signatures? What data types do they pass? How do you handle memory allocation? Are you trying to pass actual objects across these boundaries?

Comment: DeleteTree can only delete memory from the DLL. The memory of the returned object is handled by the DLL's memory manager, not by your app. Treating the returned object as object in your app is impossible (or at least very dangerous or tricky). Only the DLL functions can treat it as object, you should simply treat it as an opaque pointer (or handle). See also: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html . It looks as if the DLL already flattens the object, so just do as in the article. But it is not entirely clear when you Free the library and when you try to call the functions.

Comment: As others already said: post a [MCVE] as part of your question. You can edit your question and add the info.

Comment: Done, hopefully it's ok now.

Comment: The string argument doesn't look good. But why can't we have a [mcve]? Don't you want to make the effort to provide one?

Comment: @Ales: that is still not compilable and not complete, so it can't be verified. So not a [MCVE].

Comment: Edit2 zeroes in on the problematic function

Comment: That is a completely different question now. Post a new one. Don't modify your previous question to ask a new one.

Comment: Please post a new question and roll back this one. And in your new code (which is terribly long, so I almost didn't read it) you are making the same mistake: you are using Delphi-specific types (in this case: dynamic arrays) to translate a C++ type. **DON'T DO THAT**! I already said you shouldn't!

Comment: FWIW, an `array of array of Single` does not translate a `float**`. A `type PPSingle = ^PSingle; PSingle = ^Single;` does.

Comment: @Rudy: I have rolledback the question, as per comment request. Thank you for the PPSingle advice, I will correct this in my code, so a different question will only be needed if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The big problem seems to be your declaration of `pBlock` as a `string`!

The declaration:

```
bool LoadTree(CSpeedTreeRT* handle, const unsigned char* pBlock, unsigned int nNumBytes);
```

should be translated as:

```
type
  TLoadTreeFunc = function(Handle: THandle; const pBlock: PByte;
                    nNumBytes: Cardinal): LongBool cdecl;
```

`unsigned char` is a `Byte`, and a pointer to it is a `PByte`. To use it, just pass a pointer to the first byte of a block you reserved (e.g. a `TBytes` that has been set to the appropriate length, using `SetLength`).

Something like:

```
var
  Block: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Block, the_required_length);
  if LoadTree(SpeedTreeHandle, @Block[0], Length(Block)) then
    // etc...
```

#### Passing the type string to a (non-Delphi) DLL

`string` is a Delphi type, and in Delphi 2009 or later, it is even a `UnicodeString`. But even if it is pre-2009, where string is an `AnsiString`, it is wrong to pass it. Both `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` are **Delphi-specific and can't be used as parameter types for a DLL written in C++**. So never declare a `char *` or `unsigned char *` as `string`, but always as `PAnsiChar` or `PByte` respectively.

---

*More info in these articles of mine: ["DLL dos and don'ts"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) and ["Pitfalls of converting"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).*

Comment: Thank you, I have made suggested changes. It has also helped me to zero in on the problematic function.

Comment: When you promote your own website [you must disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @BrakNicku: I am merely pointing to my own (hopefully helpful) articles on my personal website. I am not promoting anything, I am a private person who is not affiliated, and I don't sell anything on that website, so there is nothing to disclose.

Comment: @BrakNicku: additionally, I gave an answer that explains everything. The links are not a replacement for the answer. The articles are just for further reading on the subject of converting from C or C++. Go and see for yourself.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I did not say that placing links is inappropriate, but as described in the previous link or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273211/3964075), this should be disclosed. I would change "More info here" to "More info on my website" and everything would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @BrakNicku: I thought it was already obvious from the URL, but here goes...